# Electron React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, babeljs

Im trying to make a Desktop App with Electron and React.

Im allerdings getting startet and the most components are working, but in my React component I need to make a new Funktion like:

```
add = () => {
  //this.setState({active: !this.state.active})
}
```

But after adding this 3 (2) Lines i get the error:

> app/app.js: Unexpected token (17:11) while parsing file: .../app/app.js

this is my package.json so far:

```
{
"name": "rac",
"productName": "rac-desktop",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "desktop",
"main": "main.js",
"scripts": {
  "start": "electron main.js",
  "watch": "watchify app/app.js -t babelify -o public/js/bundle.js -- debug --verbose"
},
"author": "timo",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
 "axios": "^0.16.2",
 "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
 "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
 "babelify": "7.3.0",
 "classnames": "2.2.5",
 "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.13",
 "electron-reload": "^1.2.2",
 "react": "^16.0.0",
 "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
 "semantic-ui-react": "^0.75.1"
} }
```

[The Repo](https://github.com/ZeroSoulEater/electronReactDesktopApp)

Comment: could you post your whole code of React component? Is it an es6 class of using `React.createClass`?

Comment: is the below helping `const add = () => {   //this.setState({active: this.state.active}); }` adding const keyword before add

Comment: You have a syntax issue as others have suggested. I know electron-react can be somewhat of a pain to setup so i put together an open source repo, i think it would help if you wanted to clone or do a diff against the repo https://github.com/plixxer/electron-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not valid syntax for a class function in Javascript.

A class has functions like so:

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    // do stuff  
  }

  // basic function
  doSomething() {
    this.test++;
  }
}
```

So in your case you just need to make add use the correct syntax for a function in a class

```
add() {
  this.setState({active: !this.state.active});
}
```

The syntax you have used is coming in the future as part of the [Class Fields Proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)